# Mysql configuration with spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have read Spring Fundamentals. Actually i visited many sites to know how to configure mysql database to spring project. But i have failed to get specific solution about it. so please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is very vague. Need some more explanation.

Comment: Please send your configuration and error you get. Otherwise the only thing we can do is to send you one of millions references to spring tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>
```

Springframework documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-datasource

Comment: Note also the javadocs from DriverManagerDataSource:
"NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new Connections on every call."